# Union acts like difference

Tags: modifiers

I stuck on this problem for a while and I have tried some solutions like remove doubles, check normal and i'm sure all the normals are facing outside... but after I done these, it still cannot union.
here is the file:https://www.dropbox.com/s/pu5zmob86w4rzwb/retopo.blend?dl=0
this is what I have:
[image]

and after I hit the union button from "Blender-Sculpt-Tools", it becomes this:
[image]

also I have tried to add the boolean modifier directly, but it shows like this, lots of dots and the head just gone. btw, i use join on head and body before, will this be the problem? but how do I separate them and use union instead of join?
[image]

Comment: Hi, be sure to check also possible negative scaling. This happens sometimes, and make reversed normals look correct. I would check your example file, but over 110MB is too much for me, just to check.

Comment: @m.ardito I checked the scaling, they are all good, but I found one of the rotation is set to -0, after I changing that, it still cannot union, so I think that's not a problem... i have already check the normals, I hit ctrl n on all the faces...

Comment: The hair mesh is a non-manifold geometry, that always causing boolean operations, make sure that the hair mesh is solid, or at least move all the non manifold geometry of the hair inside the head mesh, so that there are no holes.

Comment: @Denis Thank you so much!! I found the broken face on the hair mesh, after re-sculpting that, the problem is fixed